# Huggingface Dataset.map shows red progress bar when batched=True

Tags: huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I have the following simple code copied from Huggingface examples:

```
model_checkpoint = "distilgpt2"

from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, use_fast=True)

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"])

from datasets import load_dataset
datasets = load_dataset('wikitext', 'wikitext-2-raw-v1')
tokenized_datasets = datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=False, num_proc=4, remove_columns=["text"])
```

When I set `batched=False` then the progress bar shows green color which indicates success, but if I set `batched=True` then the progress bar shows red color and does not reach 100%. Does that mean my `map` function failed or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely a bug in the printing logic, not in processing itself.
Some relevant discussion at discuss.huggingface.co is [here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/while-tokenizing-the-dataset-im-getting-this-type-of-error/24779) and on GitHub it is [here](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/5117).